# How can I interpret HTML from TempData using MVC4?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view, tempdata

I try to display a `TempData` list with HTML balise inside. Is it possible to interpret the balise and not only display it ?

This is code example to illustrate what I want.

Controller :

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
ls.Add("<div> First div </div>");
ls.Add("<div> Another div </div>");
ls.Add("<div> Another div again </div>");
TempData.Add("ModelLs", ls);
```

View :

```
var ls = (List<string>)TempData["ModelLs"];
foreach (string str in ls)
{
    @str
}
```

And I'd like to display 3 "real" div on my page (and not 3 `"<div> .... </div>"`). How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you ask about `@(new HtmlString(str))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood you right, you would like to display string as HTML markup?

```
var ls = (List<string>)TempData["ModelLs"];
foreach (string str in ls)
{
    @(new HtmlString(str))
}
```

`Html.Raw()` works too :

```
var ls = (List<string>)TempData["ModelLs"];
foreach (string str in ls)
{
    @(Html.Raw(str))
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Btw, `Html.Raw()` works too. I have a problem somewhere else, that's why Html isn't interpreted. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) it returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

```
var ls = (List<string>)TempData["ModelLs"];
foreach (string str in ls)
{
    Html.Raw(str)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Below code worked fine for me***

```
                                       @{var ls = (List<string>)TempData["ModelLs"];}

                                        <ul>
                                        @foreach (var str in ls)
                                        {
                                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                                            {
                                                <li>
                                                    @Html.Label(str)
                                                </li>
                                                <br />
                                            }
                                        }
                                        </ul>
```